# Solidify problem with material offset

Tags: materials, shaders, solidify-modifier

I'm new to shaders and I was testing an outline shader tutorial I found online, but when I used the solidify modifier, it just didn't work. I tried changing the thickness but then this happened.

The blue "triangle" is the second material.

Anyone has any idea to what might have caused this?

Link to the .blend: https://www.mediafire.com/file/nefry1j1czzel9n/box.blend/file

(Im using Eevee render engine on Blender 2.81a)
[image: Image that shows what happened]

Comment: please provide blend file

Comment: i added the .blend file now

Comment: In your modifier, you select normal flipping https://i.imgur.com/B2wbLHz.png

Comment: Even after flipping the normals again, the problem persists.

Comment: Just as a comment for anyone else, I loaded the file in 2.93.5 and didn't see the same thing.  (The outline is not set up properly, but not in a way that reproduces the image shown.)  So it's not really worth downloading the file unless you're going to be opening it in 2.81a.

Comment: @Nathan did you manage to fix it? If so, please tell me, maybe i can use it for this version too.

Comment: I loaded it in 2.93.5 and it didn't look like your image, so I figured that it depends on the version.

Comment: If you can then update to the latest Blender 2.83 LTS (https://www.blender.org/download/lts/). That's the 2.8 version with bug fixes. The model looks fine in Blender 2.83.9. Uncheck the [X] Flip Normals option in the modifier settings.

Comment: Thanks @Blunder, i updated to the last version instead, when i redid the tutorial this time it worked.